# How to add http:// prefix to subdomain redirect in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, subdomain, mod-rewrite, http

I am rewriting a subdomain URL with a query (`cart.example.net/ProductDetail.jsp?LISTID=7C0400-1101763508`) to a www subdomain (`www.example.net/product-category/product`).

The problem I am facing is the URL link doesn't have the `http://` (eg. `cart.example.net`) and that is going to a 404 on the server (not a 404 on the website). That isn't happening on subdomain links that have the `http` already (eg. `http://cart.example.net`).  I believe the solution is to add the `http` in `.htaccess` if that is possible.

Any help on adding the `http://` in `.htaccess` or any other possible solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The problem I am facing is the url link doesn't have the http" - Are you saying the URL in the `href` attribute is missing the entire protocol + slashes (ie. `http://`), or just the protocol + colon (ie. `http:`)?

Comment: It is missing the entire protocol + slashes.

Comment: In that case it's going to be seen as a _relative_ URL by the browser. Presumably you can't fix this link directly on the page? Do you have any other _relative_ links? Can you edit the page to add a `base` element in the `head`? Is this on many pages, at different levels in the URL/directory structure?

Comment: Unfortunately, This url is coming from a link on a Pinterest pin that we have no direct control over. There are about 3 other similar pins from subdomain links without http://.  Ideally, we would like to go to the new product page but if worse came to worse, we would like to make sure traffic doesn't arrive at that funky server 404 page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding. So, are these intended to be inbound links to your site? The links themselves are not on your site?! What/where do they resolve to? "a 404 on the server (not a 404 on the website)" - a 404 on _your_ server?

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help.  They are links made by queries on an old version of the website and have been pinned to Pinterest boards.   Somehow when the queries were made or pinned, the http:// was not included.   When they are clicked they do not go to our normal 404 page on the website but to a page that says "The server can not find the requested page: "cart.example.net/ProductDetail.jsp?LISTID=7C0400-1101763508".Please forward this error screen to cart.example.net's WebMaster.

Comment: "they do not go to our normal 404 page" - But they are actually getting to your website domain? It's just that if the `http://` is missing from a Pinterest link then I can't see how they would even get to your site?! What is the actual URL that is being requested?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am facing is the URL link doesn't have the `http://` (eg. `cart.example.net`)

If the URL link (ie. value of the `href` attribute) is missing the protocol and simply starts `cart.example.net` then the browser will naturally see this URL as *relative*. So, assuming this link is on a page whose URL is `http://example.com/path/to/page`, then the browser will resolve this URL to:

```
http://example.com/page/to/cart.example.net/ProductDetail.jsp?LISTID=7C0400-1101763508
```

If this *malformed* link appears on your site (ie. `example.com`) then you could (*theoretically*) use mod_rewrite in your root `.htaccess` file to redirect/correct this URL. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^LISTID=7C0400-1101763508$
RewriteRule cart\.example.net/ProductDetail\.jsp$ http://www.example.net/product-category/product? [R=301,L]
```

However, if the link is on your site, then you should correct the HTML source, not implement a redirect!

> Unfortunately, This url is coming from a link on a Pinterest pin that we have no direct control over. .... and that is going to a 404 on the server (not a 404 on the website).

If the link is on an external domain (eg. Pinterest) then this *relative* URL is naturally going to resolve relative to the external domain and will never reach your website or your server! So, you can't do anything about this at your end.

The "404 on the server" is presumably not *your* server, but a server under the control of Pinterest.